# Why does // in a string does not start a comment in C++?

Tags: c++, string, string-literals

I am printing a line like this

```
cout<<"Hello //stackoverflow";
```

And this produces the following output

```
Hello //stackoverflow
```

I want to know why it does not give me an error as I commented half of the statement and there should be

```
missing terminating " character
```

error.

Comment: The language would be kind of limiting if you couldn't have `"//"` in a string literal

Comment: You use the comment prefix within string _literal_, which means that the compiler treats that portion of the source code as an opaque piece of text.

Answer (score 11):

The grammar of C++ (like most of programming languages) is context-sensitive. Simply, `//` does not start a comment if it is within a string literal.

Answer (score 8):

For an in depth analysis of this, you'd have to refer to the language grammar, and the string literal production rules in particular.

Informally speaking, the fact that `//` appears in the quoted string literal means that it does not denote a comment block. The same applies to `/*` and `*/`.

The converse applies to other constructs, where *maximal munch* requires parsing into the token denoting the start of a comment block; a space is needed before the pointer dereference operator in

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n = 1;
    int* p = &n;
    cout << 1 / *p; // Removing the final space will fail compilation.
}
```

Comment: Addendum, as of C++11 allows `unique_ptr<vector<int>>` without needing a space between the last two `>>`.  That's a violation of the maximal munch policy that otherwise is the norm.  I believe the allowance is generally considered a good idea, but I'm sure there is a contingent that is unhappy with the change.

Answer (score 1):

In easy terms, This is because everything inside quotes is recognized as a string and so the computer does not evaluate // as the way to start a comment.